Type "ListType" cannot be assigned to type "T@ListPattern" (which comes from T = TypeVar("T", bound=ListType))
I am trying to do something when 2 objects have the same type. However, after checking if(type(list_type) == type(other_list_type)), Pylance still thinks that the types are different: Type "ListType" cannot be assigned to type "T@ListPattern"PylancereportArgumentType.
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

class LetterList(BaseModel):
    letter: str

class NumberList(BaseModel):
    numbers: list[int]

class BulletPointsList(BaseModel):
    bullet: str


ListType = LetterList | NumberList | BulletPointsList | None

T = TypeVar("T", bound=ListType)

class ListPattern(Generic[T]):

    def test(self, list_type: T, other_list_type: ListType):
        if(type(list_type) == type(other_list_type)):
            self.handle_same_type(
                list_type=list_type,
                # Argument of type "ListType" cannot be assigned to parameter "other_list_type" of type "T@ListPattern" in function "handle_same_type"
                other_list_type=other_list_type 
            )

    def handle_same_type(
        self,
        list_type: T,
        other_list_type: T
    ):
        pass

pattern = ListPattern[LetterList]

I think this has to do with the use of generics. Is there way to check that other_list_type has type T before passing it to the function handle_same_type?
